# UItextview vs UIWebView for showing long attributed text in the iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to show a variable text on my universal iOS application. I load the texts from SQLite DB as `NSString` and almost each line of the text has separated atributes like Color. So I need to use `AttributedText`. Also I want to support both ios 7 and ios 7 and also in future iOS 8.

I noticed that there is two general ways: 1- Using UITextView 2- Using UIWebView.

I am wondering what is the advantages and disadvantages of using above features and witch of the is better for showing long length and very attributed text. And also is there any other solution for showing this texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest advantage of using `UIWebView` is that you can render an HTML content through it -- any HTML content, since it is backed by WebKit.

On the other hand, `UIWebView` will add a noticeable delay from the moment when you add it as a subview to the moment when it will have finished to render the HTML.

You could also give a look at alternatives like [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) and others that you may find on GitHub. RTLabel is built on top of Core Text and supports HTML-like markup.

EDIT:

> Some of them are about 40000 characters. It should be about 1000 paragraphs and each paragraph 1 line.

My suggestion is to go for some kind of paging to let the user move comfortably through all that text (40k chars would be like 25-30 book pages). This would improve UX and it would also make feasible the implementation through a `UITextView` -- performance-wise.

If you do not want paging and want just one scrolling view, then `UIWebView` could be better for your case since it should also do some kind of optimisation regarding portions of the page that are not displayed.

Finally, as a side node, since you specify that your text has a fixed structure (1000 40-chars lines), another option which you could consider is using a `UITableView` for this, provided that you can display each paragraph in a single cell row. This would be the most efficient solution since you have short pieces of text and the table view to handle their allocation/deallocation based on which ones (usually a small subset) are displaying.

Comment: I have not any HTML tag. All the content are texts of a book. I have some problems with textview that has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355793/nstextview-with-long-nsmutableattributedtext-low-scrolling-and-loading-speed but do not received any information. I made some search in this days and noticed about this two way. So I wondered about using WebView or TextView. So it is right to using text view for showing attributed text of a book?It seems that it is the best way.right?

Comment: Would you like having some kind of paging? How long is each text you put in the view?

Comment: Some of them are about 40000 characters. It should be about 1000 paragraphs and each paragraph  1 line. Each line have a attribute text.

Comment: very thanks. Actually is it possible to show strings that is not in the HTML tags on the uiwebview?

Comment: You are welcome. I don't think you can display non HTML content in `UIWebView`…